# Is it possible to reproduce Double-slit experiment by myself at home?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, home-experiment, double-slit-experiment

I want to reproduce this experiment by myself. What I need for this. What parameters of slits and laser/another light source it needs? Is it possible to make [DIY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_it_yourself)-detector?

Comment: The detector could be a whole separate question, especially if you are thinking of building a photomultiplier or something. Honestly, a successful experiment will show itself qualitatively upon visual inspection. If you want a more quantitative analysis, perhaps taking a RAW picture and looking at pixel values will suffice.

Comment: You might be interested in quantum eraser experiment, that can also be reproduced at home, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-6St1rDbzo

Comment: duplicate or near-duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38440/

Comment: I forgot about this possibility making the double-slit: use MS Paint or Inkscape and print them on overhead transparency.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to perform the experiment in the comfort of your own home.  The simplest setup I have seen (as depicted in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UANVMIajqlA), and other youtube videos) is to use a laser pointer and pencil lead, but you can certainly be more systematic and cut slits in some opaque material as well.

I would encourage you to experiment to answer the question of how far apart the slits need to be etc., but some basic math behind this is as follows:  If the slits are a distance $d$ apart, if the light has wavelength $\lambda$, and if the distance between the slits and the screen is $L$, then the spacing $\Delta y$ between successive fringes on the wall will approximately be
$$
  \Delta y \approx \frac{\lambda L}{d}
$$
So let's say the laser is red so that $\lambda\approx 700 \mathrm{nm}$,  the slits are $1\,\mathrm{mm}$ apart, and the screen is $1.5\,\mathrm m$ away from the slits, then we have
$$
  \Delta y \approx \frac{(700\,\mathrm{nm})(1.5\,\mathrm{m})}{1\,\mathrm{mm}} = 1.05\,\mathrm{mm}
$$
So you can actually try this and see if your results agree! (I might actually try this myself come to think of it; thanks for the question!)

Cheers!

Comment: You can also use human hairs to produce at least single-slit diffraction patterns. Two hairs/graphite leads can in principle also do it, through [Babinet's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet's_principle).

Comment: What's about detector near one slit?

Comment: I would add from my own experience that cutting slits in an opaque material often produces slits that are not entirely negligible in width (compared to $d$), so there may be a broad single-slit pattern modulating the double-slit pattern that is sought.

Comment: What's about depth of slits? Does it have sense?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, though the result does depend somewhat upon your definition of "at home".

Simply seeing the interference pattern is as simple as a laser pointer and a few narrow apertures (see the other answer(s))

[People have successfully even done single-photon interference at home!](http://www.teralab.co.uk/Experiments/Youngs_Slits/Youngs_Slits_Menu.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Laser pointer, nit comb, bit of cardboard from a cereal box to control the number of slits. Works perfectly!