# Is there any quantum experiments or effects that you can do at home?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, everyday-life, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, home-experiment

I have heard that you can do the double slit experiment, but is there any other experiments like particle entanglement or observer-induced state collapse?

Comment: Related if not duplicate of [Quantum mechanics and everyday nature](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65397/)

Comment: Do you have a magnet? Magnetism is a purely quantum mechanical phenomenon, so is every atom in your body. There is no such thing as observer induced collapse, that's just a pretty bad misnomer for Born's rule. There is a not totally nutty idea that the flow of time may be due to entanglement, so if you have a watch, you would basically be doing an entanglement experiment. The list goes on...

Comment: @gonenc thanks for that, the duplicate you cite is much better than my attempt, should have read that first.

Comment: Tonic water and UV light, the quinine will absorb the UV but irradiate blue light (can be explain with Bohr's model for electron transitions).