# Does anyone know how/where I could view the Double slit experiment in person?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, observers

I want to see the double slit experiment in person! The one where the observer effects the wave/particle state of an electron. Where would I be able to view this experiment? Is it on display in any museums? I'd probably be able to go to any university with a physics program to see it in person I suppose....

Comment: I'm voting to close this list question (v1) as off-topic because it seems to be about geographic locations rather than physics.

Comment: @Qmechanic, give it a rest already. It's easier to just answer his question.

Comment: @Nick Perez, I was about to answer the question but Qmechanic kinda spoiled the mood. Anyway, the best way to see the double-slit in person is to do it yourself. What you're referring to in your question is the "Quantum Eraser" version of the double-slit, which has to do not with electrons, however, but photons. All you need is a simple laser pointer and a pair of polarizing 3D movie-glasses. Here's a video that outlines the whole process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-6St1rDbzo (skip ahead to see the guy actually do it)

Comment: For [DIY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_it_yourself) [YDSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54052/2451 and links therein.

Comment: What's with this endless fascination for a trivial experiment that everybody can do at home with a dark room, a few rays of sunshine, a little bit of aluminum foil (or some pieces of an old broken mirror) and a razor blade? Not even a laser is needed.

Comment: @DavidReishi: That's another trivial experiment that doesn't teach anybody anything of value about nature.

Comment: The double-slit experiment exposes quantum effects only when individual photons are seen constructing the interference pattern, and particularly strikingly as a compound pattern arises when a fraction of the photons are located at a slit while others are left unobserved. Without decreasing the source emission rate at this level, you just get classical light wave behavior, aka optics.