# Double Slit Experiment With Air

Tags: experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, atmospheric-science, interference

I can see interference patterns in liquids and in light, but I don't see it in the air that surrounds us. I don't see leaves align in an interference pattern on the other side of a picket fence. The closest I could find after some googling was air moving over the surface of water. So I did this[image].The cigar smoke is drawn through the paint sprayer and shot through a double slit, made from razor blades and a very thin wire. A white piece of cloth is on the other side of the double slit. The smoke will stain where the air concentrates. Here's what I saw after burning four inches of a cigar.[image] So the question is why no interference pattern on the cloth or in nature?

Comment: The smoke is about 0.01 microns. The slit was just as tight as I could physically make it. Yes, I peeked.  Just couldn't resist.

Comment: The slit was tight enough to produce an interference pattern when a red laser beam passed through it.

Comment: Did you read this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38440/tried-to-do-the-double-slit-experiment-failed-why?rq=1  just in case it has any relevance

Comment: You know what did better than I do obviously, but this line in the link above caught my eye...  **Expand the beam with a lens. As long as you have one laser source, the fluctuations in intensity are correlated and you should have an easier time than with an incoherent source** does  that apply to your setup in any way , I wonder