# White-light double-slit experiment with an LED

Tags: double-slit-experiment, home-experiment

[This answer and comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/373910/40686) state that you can perform Young's two-slit interference experiment with white light and get a pattern of colored interference fringes.  I've got some white LEDs lying around that I could use as a point source of light.  Would one of these work as a light source for the experiment, or would the decidedly non-blackbody spectrum mess things up?

Answer (score 1):

The point of the white light interference experiment is that all the light is interfering whatever the wavelength. The spectrum doesn't matter.

ps. Getting a white light pattern can be tricky, you could try with a single color LED first, or better still a laser pointer.

pps. A bare LED probably isn't enough of a point source for white light fringes - you might need a lens and a pinhole