# How to make DIY flight detector for double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, double-slit-experiment, interference

I want to reproduce double slit experiment. So, is it possible to build flight detector (situated near one slit) at home? Is it possible to buy it somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16783/12613 and Googling finds lots of stuff like http://sciencekit.com/young-rsquo-s-double-slit-apparatus/p/IG0023809/ and http://miyakishman.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/diy-double-slit-experiment.html